# web3.eth.currentProvider.send() - what does this function return and is there alternative?

Tags: web3js

I can't find this method in the web3js documentation anywhere.

It doesn't seem to return a promise and I can only use a callback function with it.

Is there any other way that I can use this method?

```
let send = httpProvider.send({
    method: "trace_transaction",
    params: [txHash],
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: "2"
}, function (err, response) {
    if(!err){
        console.log("Details of each trace");
        for(let i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++){
            if(web3.utils.isHex(response.result[i].action.value)){
                let str = web3.utils.hexToNumberString(response.result[i].action.value);
                console.log(str);
            }

        }
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

console.log(send);
//undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

"provider.send()" is a low level function that sends a JSON-RPC command directly to the web3's provider.

Sometimes it is used to send non-standard commands to the client, for example "trace_transaction" is a geth command to debug a transaction.